# Service Container Alias only for a certain environment

Tags: symfony

Symfony 2.8.7 I have a simple alias definition in my services.yml:

```
    h4cc_alice_fixtures:
         alias: h4cc_alice_fixtures.manager
```

This works perfectly in DEV because in my AppKernel h4cc is registered:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
    //...
    ];

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new h4cc\AliceFixturesBundle\h4ccAliceFixturesBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

In PROD now I get an dependency injection error because of course h4cc_alice_fixtures.manager cannot be resolved.

I want to have h4ccAliceFixturesBundle only in DEV and TEST but currently I have only one services.yml.

Is there a way to define the alias only for DEV and TEST?

**UPDATE**:

As there is something like:

```
my_service:
    class: Acme\AcmeBundle\Services\MyService
    arguments: [ '@tenant_user_service', '@?debug.stopwatch' ]
```

which is only injecting Stopwatch when App is in debug-mode...

I thought there might be existing something similar for Alias, too.

Comment: What about configure dev services in a service_dev.yml and include it via config_dev.yml?

Comment: thanks, I've updated my question to clarify what my expectation could be, but perhaps you're simply right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have separate services.yml similar what you have already with your **routing_dev.yml**. In the imports section of your **config_dev.yml** and **config_test.yml** you can replace the existing line:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
```

with following entry:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services_dev.yml }
```

like you have it in your global config.yml already. Just add your suffix to the files.